# Pure Assets SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

What is the best practice for creating a pure assets swf?
It has to have zero code, I need to load it externally on IOS.

I'm aware of starling's AssetManager, but it doesn't fit my unique circumstances, the assets have to be compiled in SWFs.

I can use embed tags and then use adt's swf stripping, but it's proving to be too much work (I'm still trying to debug the matter), it also seems a bit of an overkill to go through such a complex process to strip code when I only need assets.

My second option is to add assets to an FLA library and give them linkages, which basically works just fine, except Flash IDE is really troublesome and has problems reading too many assets, which will definitely be a huge headache on the long run (these assets were being compiled just fine with embed tags).

Is there a way to purely compile assets with linkages or some sort of other reference to them, without having to worry about the Flash IDE not being able to read them, and without having any code on the SWF?

Comment: What is a "Pure Assets SWF"?

Comment: A SWF that contains nothing but assets (e.g. textures, sounds...), no code.

Answer (score 1):

Look into JSFL, with that you can export all symbols into their own swf with just their asset in it (symbol linkage is considered coded swf in Ios). You can even strip all code with JSFL. Not too hard to learn it's Javascript. Advantage is all those individual swf will be small and easy to load or embed.

For embedding of course it's cumbersome to do it one by one but you can put together a simple AIR app that will go through a folder and write the embed code for you in a file, then you copy and paste, easy.

Comment: Do you mean literally "converting" each single asset to SWF, or will each SWF contain many assets?

Comment: Each single asset to its own swf.

Comment: It misses the point for me, the whole reason I'm using SWFs is to pack many assets into a single file, for loading purposes.

Comment: Not really, it is possible that much I know. I'm just trying to find the best way to do it.

Comment: It's possible but difficult to manage. You are only trying to go the easy way I can understand that but you should make your life easier already and do it the right way. You can have hundreds of assets of different kind without having to enter their path manually anywhere. Write a little app that does that for you and that's all.

Comment: I have the feeling your main problem is that you hate coding and you try as much as possible to avoid coding. This might be a problem if you want to make a career out of it.

Comment: Sorry for being direct, but my problem is that your solution doesn't really solve anything.
I have nothing to gain by putting each single asset into its own SWF, instead I could simply load the assets one by one in their current formats.
I'm trying to pack many assets into a single SWF in order to avoid many requests to the server, each request has an overhead and the combined overheads result in a very slow and inefficient download speed, while loading a single SWF that contains all the assets takes only one server request.

Comment: I'm familiar with JSFL, and the solutions I mentioned in my question were both done using JSFL - I recursively loop over all the assets, in the first solution I created embed tags, which I didn't even need to copy paste I just write an .as file with JSFL, and in the second one I create flas, add assets to library, and publish. Both solutions are completely automated.
However like I mentioned in my question, both solutions are incomplete and come with different problems.

Comment: there's a difference between loading externally on Ios as you said and loading from a server. If you just want to load everything at once from a server for an Ios app then zip everything, download that zip, extract and save on disk.

Comment: symbol linkage is considered coded swf in Ios - thanks, i've been stuck on this for some time